# Installing datacommons from sunlight

Tags: installation

I know strictly nothing from python and I am installing datacommons from the sunlightlabs. So I followed step by step the README.md https://github.com/sunlightlabs/datacommons

First, it is said in the doc to add to the virtualenv dc_data, dc_matcchbox but I didn't find them. But I went to the final step to run ./manage.py runserver so I had the following message :

```
(datacommons)newben@newben-VirtualBox:~/share-ubuntu/sunlightlabs-datacommons-e3ff1a3$ ./manage.py runserver
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /home/mbenchoufi)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing './manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)
```

In the 'sunlightlabs-datacommons-e3ff1a3' folder, I downloaded and put the files from github.
By the way I didin't understand how to deal with the settings file.

Could someone help me understand how to install datacommons ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you just downloaded the git repository instead of cloning it? And .git is not present in the repo directory?

then you should use:

```
git clone https://github.com/sunlightlabs/datacommons.git
```

instead

(also you should check if you have the right python version installed)